# RaphaelJS Multiple animate same element

Tags: raphael

I currently have the following working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmns)

```
var moveAnim = Raphael.animation({ progress: 1 }, 5000, 'bounce').repeat(Infinity);
```

I animate a circle along a line.

I also want to make the circle flash at the same time but I can't seem to work out a way to do this?

I thought about adding the circle to a set and applying the additional animation to this but I can't see to get this either!

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say 'flash at the same time', do you mean something related to the same 'bounce' easing, or a different easing ?

Comment: While the circle is moving along the line I want it to glow/flash while it is moving.. the bounce is included in the move, so this isn't relevant is it?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to just flash at a constant rate, or do you mean something like you want it to flash when it hits the wall is what I was meaning (also with opacity, or scale or something else ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution that I came up with is a looping callback. The very sound of a looping callback sounds ugly but I guess thats what an animation is?

It does appear that you can attach multiple animations to an element! Here's a [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7aBKA/)

```
function animateIn() {
        flashingCircle.animate({ fill: '#f00' }, 1000, animateOut);
    }
    function animateOut() {
        flashingCircle.animate({ fill: '#fff' }, 1000, animateIn);
    }
    animateIn();
```

Comment: Interesting, I had problems with 2 animations, I wonder if that was just my bad coding, or if its because these animations are slightly different format. Good to know, and its a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack and I make no attempt to hide it, but it could be made a bit nicer.

There's a couple of problems depending on 'how' you want to animate the flash. The main problem is having 2 simultaneous animation on the same object, as Raphael doesn't do this (to my knowledge). Its easier if you want to animate an alternate attribute than the same one. If you want to animate a scale to indicate a flash, you will need to append the scale transform to the end of the path transform string ('t,s').

Example here, just uses opacity attribute.

Probably the nicest method would be to include something that figures out time running and amends an attribute manually within the animation function (paper.customAttributes.progress). However, that will probably take a bit longer.

Another alternative could be to animate another object off screen, that does all the calculations for you. It feels a bit ugly, but should work.

So earlier we create a dummy object off screen...

```
var dummy = paper.circle(-100,-100,10).attr({ opacity: 0 });
```

Within the progress func, you can then set the real circles opacity to be the same as the offscreen one.

```
this.attr('opacity', dummy.attr('opacity'));
```

And we get the dummy animation triggering later

```
dummy.animate(flashingAnim);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmns/2/)

As mentioned, I think there are cleaner ways, but may involve you writing a small linear animation func separately, but this may help if performance isn't an issue and you don't mind extra elements in the dom.

Comment: certainly answers my question and I don't think it's too ugly...i did find an alternative way which I'll post below! ta